# Low energy effective action of bosonic string different in GSW and Polchinski/Tong?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, conventions, curvature, effective-field-theory

In Superstring Theory vol.1 by Green, Schwarz and Witten (GSW) the low energy effective action of the bosonic string is given by:

$$S=-\frac{1}{2k_0^2}\int d^{26}x\sqrt{-g}e^{-2\Phi}({\cal R}-4\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi+\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\rho}H^{\mu\nu\rho}).\tag{GSW3.4.57}$$

But in String Theory vol.1 by Polchinski and in [David Tong's online lectures](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) on string theory the low energy effective action of the bosonic string is given by:

$$S=\frac{1}{2k_0^2}\int d^{26}x\sqrt{-g}e^{-2\Phi}({\cal R}+4\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\rho}H^{\mu\nu\rho}). \tag{P3.7.20/T7.16}$$

As far as I can tell they are using the same conventions so why the difference?

Comment: The real question is: are the $\beta$ functions the same in GSW and Polchinski. In Polchinski the effective action is given and it is stated  that these lead to the $\beta$ function equations. I have checked this calculation in detail and have found it to be correct. I have the detailed calculation available, if you want it.

Comment: Ok thanks I accept the Polchinski action leads to his $\beta$ functions. I would need to check if GSW $\beta$ functions are same as Polchinski.

Answer (score 3):

Since all the mentioned authors use the same Minkowskian signature $(-,+,\ldots, +)$, it seems the difference is caused by different sign convention for the [scalar curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_convention#Curvature).