# Sign Wrong in Effective Action of Bosonic String?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, wick-rotation

In David Tong's [Lectures in String Theory Chapter 7](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/seven.pdf) he sketches a derivation of the low-energy effective action of the bosonic string $(7.16)$:
$$S=\frac{1}{2k_0^2}\int d^{26}X\sqrt{-G}e^{-2\Phi}\Big(\mathcal{R}-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda}+4\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi\Big).\tag{1}$$
Towards the bottom of page $162$ he states that the stress-energy tensor $T_{\alpha\beta}$ is given by
$$T_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\alpha\beta}}.\tag{2}$$
But normally the stress-energy tensor is defined by the negative of the expression in Eqn $(2)$. For example see the expression for $T_{\mu\nu}$ in the [Derivation of Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action#Derivation_of_Einstein_field_equations) section of the Einstein-Hilbert Action Wiki page:
$$T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta(\sqrt{-g}\mathcal{L}_M)}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\tag{3}.$$
If we use an expression like Eqn $(2)$, without the minus sign, as a definition of $T_{\mu\nu}$ rather than Eqn $(3)$ then the Einstein-Hilbert action has to change to:
$$S=\int\Big[-\frac{1}{2\kappa}\mathcal{R}+\mathcal{L}_M\Big]\sqrt{-g}\ d^4x.$$
Thus to be consistent with the definition of $T_{\alpha\beta}$ in Eqn$(2)$ the low-energy effective action should be given by:
$$S=\frac{1}{2k_0^2}\int d^{26}X\sqrt{-G}e^{-2\Phi}\Big(\mathcal{-R}-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\lambda}H^{\mu\nu\lambda}+4\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi\Big).\tag{4}$$
Has David Tong got the sign of the $\mathcal{R}$ term wrong in his expression for the low-energy effective action of the bosonic string?

If he has got it wrong then so have the authors of [Sigma Models and String Theory](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/sigma.pdf), which David Tong cites, as they also use a definition of $T_{\alpha\beta}$ without a minus sign (2.3) to derive a bosonic string effective action with a positive $\mathcal{R}$ term (3.56).

Comment: You are mixing up Euclidean and Lorentzian signatures. You get extra minus signs when you go from one signature to the other via a Wick rotation.

Comment: @Prahar Please convert that to an answer, preferably with more detail.

Comment: The Polyakov action in (1.22)/(1.30) has an overall minus sign, therefore $T_{ab}$ above (1.30) or in (4.4) has a minus sign, so that (1.32) looks nice. In (7.1) however the action $S$ has an overall $+$ sign, that's why $T_{ab}$ on p. 162 gets changed to a plus sign. There are comments around (1.30) and (4.4) on how the overall coefficients are just choices, e.g. why does your (2) getting a factor of $2 \pi$ compared to your (3) not cause any concerns.

Comment: Also: see around (4.4), where one uses the Euclidean metric (e.g. immediately below (4.4), yet he *still* has a minus sign in (4.4), so at least in this context it's not about the signature it's just about the overall choice of sign in the actions in (1.30) vs. (7.1).

Comment: Even if an assumed negative sign in front of the expression for $T_{\alpha\beta}$ on page 162 is cancelled by an assumed negative sign in front of the Polyakov action (7.1) I'm still concerned that Tong doesn't explicitly show the negative signs in front of these two expressions. Missing out the minus sign in front of (7.1) particularly seems like asking for trouble to me but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Sure, well section 3.4 of Green-Schwarz-Witten has the minus signs all throughout for comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632350

Answer (score 1):

1. Eq. (1) on p. 168 is apparently in Minkowskian signature because of the minus under the square root. On p. 9 [Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) explains it is $(-,+,\ldots,+)$ sign convention.
2. Eq. (2) on p. 162 is apparently in Euclidean signature because of the Kronecker delta $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ in the first formula on p. 162.
3. Eq. (3) on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action#Derivation_of_Einstein_field_equations) is in Minkowskian signature $(-,+,+,+)$.

   See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228185/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632350/2451) related Phys.SE posts.